# Error when joining dataframes using AWS Glue Container

Tags: aws-glue-spark

I tried joining two sample dataframes using the code below :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate() 
glueContext = GlueContext(sc) 
inputDF = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://bayu-wbi-test/customers.csv"]}, format = "csv")
DF1 = inputDF.toDF()
DF2 = inputDF.toDF()

DoubleDF = DF1.join(DF2,DF1.col0 == DF2.col0)
DoubleDF.show()
```

however i encounter this error when i run it in my Glue container :

```
An error was encountered:
An error occurred while calling o135.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ResultStage 4 ($anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1 at FutureTask.java:266) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason: org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: Stream is corrupted  at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:772)    at org.apache.spark.storage.BufferReleasingInputStream.read(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:845)  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)   at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$2$$anon$3.readSize(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:113)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$2$$anon$3.next(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:129)   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeRowSerializerInstance$$anon$2$$anon$3.next(UnsafeRowSerializer.scala:110)   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:494)  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)  at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.next(CompletionIterator.scala:29)   at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.next(InterruptibleIterator.scala:40)  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:351)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:898)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:898)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)     at
```

This container is running on my local machine and i've tried increasing the spark driver memory.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Think it might be related to this issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34790

According to this reported issue: https://github.com/delta-io/delta/issues/841
A possible workaround is to set
sparkConf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.fetchShuffleBlocksInBatch", "false")